# TinkerPop 3 - Get Vertex and edge property

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I would like to return all vertex's that have a certain edge and the date an edge was added but I'm just not getting my head around it.

i.e.

```
g.V().out("likes").map{it -> it.dateLiked = it.outE("likes").property("addedOn"); it;}
```

In SQL terms I can think of it like;

```
SELECT item.*,
       edge.addedOn
  FROM item_table item,
       edge_mapping_table edge
 WHERE item.id = edge.item_id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way you might do it using the "modern" toy graph as an example:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().outE('knows').as('e').
           inV().as('v').
           select('e','v').by('weight').by(valueMap())
==>[e:0.5,v:[name:[vadas],age:[27]]]
==>[e:1.0,v:[name:[josh],age:[32]]]
```

So, instead of getting the "addedOn" from the "likes" edge and the properties of the "item" vertex, I want to get the "weight" from "knows" edge and the properties of the "person" vertex. In the first line, we traverse out on the "knows" edge and label it as 'e', then we traverse to the adjacent `in` person vertex and label it as 'v'.  Finally we select the values of those two labels and apply `by` transforms on them. The `by` are applied in round-robin fashion so the first `by` is applied to 'e' and the second one is applied to the 'v'.

The use of `valueMap` is a bit of a convenience, but typically you would know the data that you wanted retrieved from the vertex just as you knew the data you would retrieve from the edge (i.e. the "weight"). To make for a slightly nicer output without all the embedded `Map` then you could do:

```
gremlin> g.V().outE('knows').as('w').
           inV().as('a','n').
           select('w','a','n').
             by('weight').by('age').by('name')
==>[w:0.5,a:27,n:vadas]
==>[w:1.0,a:32,n:josh]
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the mini lesson! Out of curiosity is there another step to then flatten it again to say [e:0.5, name: vadas, age: 27] ?

Comment: I suppose you could unwrap the map, but perhaps better to be more specific about the data you wanted in the first place. As you wouldn't typically do "select * from table" in SQL you wouldn't typically grab all the data from a vertex. As such, I presented a slightly different solution.